# ServiceStack: Routes.AddFromAssembly still uses /json/reply path and no URL-niceness for properties

Tags: web-services, servicestack

I have a ServiceStack self-hosted webservice, using the `AppSelfHostBase`.

WHen the Configure method is executed, I have this:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    Config.RouteNamingConventions = new List<RouteNamingConventionDelegate> {
        RouteNamingConvention.WithRequestDtoName,
        RouteNamingConvention.WithMatchingAttributes,     
        RouteNamingConvention.WithMatchingPropertyNames,  
    };

    Routes.AddFromAssembly(typeof(ServiceStackHost).Assembly);
```

and I expected the following service to be executed under `/StartBankIdAuthentication` path, but it resides under `/json/reply/StartBankIdAuthentication` instead.

```
public class StartBankIdAuthentication : IReturn<StartBankIdAuthenticationResponse>
{
    public string IdNbr { get; set; }
}
```

Also, is there an *automatic way* to make the properties in the DTO to be under "sub-paths", like `/StartBankIdAuthentication/1234` instead of the `/StartBankIdAuthentication?IdNbr=1234`?

I know I can manually add the `Route` attribute, but it seems cumbersome and also messy in many ways (not Typed, error-prone etc).

Answer (score 0):

> I expected the following service to be executed under `/StartBankIdAuthentication` path, but it resides under `/json/reply/StartBankIdAuthentication` instead.

The `/json/reply/StartBankIdAuthentication` is a pre-defined route that's always available by default, they have no relation to [Auto Generated Routes](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#auto-route-generation-strategies).

The default Route generation strategies you've listed are [already registered by default](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/31d6b3610dcbe6209eeab63c84d6dbf1ee3a9789/src/ServiceStack/HostConfig.cs#L120) and are what's applied when you use `Routes.AddFromAssembly()`. You should only override with route strategies you want in addition to the defaults, and you should use `SetConfig()` for any configuration in ServiceStack, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    RouteNamingConventions = { MyCustomRouteStrategy }
});
```

The implementation for the different Route Strategies available in ServiceStack are in [RouteNamingConvention.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/RouteNamingConvention.cs), you'll need to register your own strategy for anything additional Route strategies you want.

By default additional routes are generated for any [`Id` or `IDs` property](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/31d6b3610dcbe6209eeab63c84d6dbf1ee3a9789/src/ServiceStack/Host/RouteNamingConvention.cs#L19-L22), the [routing docs shows examples of how they can be customized](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#auto-route-generation-strategies):

The existing rules can be further customized by modifying the related static properties, e.g:

```
RouteNamingConvention.PropertyNamesToMatch.Add("UniqueId");
RouteNamingConvention.AttributeNamesToMatch.Add("DefaultIdAttribute");
```

Which will make these request DTOs:

```
class MyRequest1
{
    public UniqueId { get; set;}
}

class MyRequest2
{
    [DefaultId]
    public CustomId { get; set;}
}
```

Generate the following routes:

```
/myrequest1
/myrequest1/{UniqueId}
/myrequest2
/myrequest2/{CustomId}
```

> I know I can manually add the Route attribute, but it seems cumbersome and also messy in many ways (not Typed, error-prone etc).

If you really want you can use `nameof()` for Typed Routes:

```
[Route("/" + nameof(StartBankAuthentication) +"/"+ nameof(StartBankAuthentication.IdNbr))]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have read the documentation, which I obviously misunderstood. So the question is, is there a way, using `RouteNamingConventions`, to create paths that start with `/` and that automatically maps all properties in the DTOs, in order, so `/SomeMethod/{FirstProp}/{SecondProp}` and so on? I know how to override the `GetRouteAttributes` and manually build the "base path", but unsure how to add the property as "parameters-in-a-path" :-)

Comment: I dont want to specify `RouteNamingConvention.PropertyNamesToMatch.Add("UniqueId");`, because that defeats the purpose; I just want to define the name and properties in the DTO, and then let ServiceStack auto-generate the rest ;-)

Comment: @Ted ServiceStack doesn't auto-generate anything, each custom [Route Convention Implementations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/RouteNamingConvention.cs) is what registers the routes which gets called for each Request DTO/Actions. If the pre-build routing conventions don't do what you need you'll need to implement and register your own. See how the existing conventions are implemented for reference.

Comment: Alright, thx. If you see my answer below, is that a good/valid/reasonable solution, or is it a bad idea, and if so, why? =)

Comment: @Ted .NET's reflection APIs are not deterministic so you shouldn't rely on the order properties are defined on the class, you'll want to make them deterministic by either sorting them by name or adding an explicit order. Also it's poor form to design HTTP APIs like this, the route should be the resource/identifier for the Service where all other properties are modifiers of that Resource i.e. shouldn't be included in the route and should be left as queryStrings.

Comment: @Ted Routes define your public API which is why everyone explicitly defines them so they can control what external routes consumers bind to, so I'd be reluctant auto generate deep routes like this where you have limited control over your API and adding/removing properties could break multiple routes clients depend on.

Comment: I see, thanks for your input. I was always under the impression that all properties should be in the path, as below, but you mean they shouldnt, but instead use the more bloated `?varName=varValue` ... I will consider this.

Comment: @Ted Yes adding properties which aren't used to identify the service on the queryString. The resource/identifier for your Service should never change, but you can liberally add additional properties to customize the request, the appropriate API design to do that for GET requests is via the queryString.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Mythz will maybe come up with a different of better solution, but I managed to achieve what I wanted by overriding the GetRouteAttributes, and by using reflection, I could create what I wanted. It looks like this:

```
public override RouteAttribute[] GetRouteAttributes(Type requestType)
{
    string fullname = requestType.FullName.Replace("AlfaOnlineServiceModel.Api.", "");
    string path = "/" + fullname.ToLower().Replace(".", "/");

    RouteAttribute[] routes = base.GetRouteAttributes(requestType);
    if (routes.Length == 0)
    {
        routes = new RouteAttribute[1];

        PropertyInfo[] pInfos = requestType.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        foreach(PropertyInfo pi in pInfos)
        {
            path += "/{" + pi.Name + "}";
        }

        routes[0] = new RouteAttribute(path);
    }
    return routes;
}
```

Which will give for example:

```
MyMethodResult
The following routes are available for this service:
All Verbs   /myCoolPath/mySubPath/myMethod/{MyProperty}
```